# Need help getting average weight of an item from a different class

Tags: java

I'm stuck on the last part of my homework assignment and just can't figure out how to complete it.

I'm tasked with taking the 3 weights (in pounds and ounces) and getting the average weight, and then printing that to the command line.  My current thought process is to get all three weights added together, and then I thought it would be as easy as dividing them by 3.  However when I attempt to do that, it throws an error saying "bad operand types for binary operator '/' "

I have two separate files.

'''

```
// a class that represents a Weight in pounds and ounces

class Weight {
  // private instant variables
  private int pounds;
  private double ounces;
  // private constant variable
  private static double OUNCES_IN_A_POUND = 16;
  

    // a method that normalizes the weight on which it was invoked
  private void normalize() {
    // while loop used to continusoulsy loop til less than 16 ounces
    while(ounces > OUNCES_IN_A_POUND) {
      // decrement 16 ounces from the ounces and increment pound by 1
      ounces -= OUNCES_IN_A_POUND;
      pounds++;
    }
  }


// method used to return total number of ounces
  private double toOunces() {
    return pounds * OUNCES_IN_A_POUND + ounces;
  }


  // constructor for pounds and ounces to be initialized
  public Weight(int pounds, double ounces) {
    this.pounds = pounds;
    this.ounces = ounces;
    // normalize the ounces
    normalize();
  }


  // a method that checks if the current object's weight is less than
  public boolean lessThan(Weight wt) {
    if(this.pounds < wt.pounds)
      return true;
    else if(this.pounds > wt.pounds)
      return false;
    else {
      if(this.ounces < wt.ounces)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
  }  
  
// a method that adds weight to the current object

  public void addTo(Weight wt) {
    this.pounds += wt.pounds;
    this.ounces += wt.ounces;
    normalize();
  }

  
// a method that returns the string 
  public String toString() {
    return pounds + " pounds " + String.format("%.2f", ounces) + " ounces";
  }

}
```

second file:

```
class Project1 {

  // a method that returns the smallest weight among 3 weights
  private static Weight findMinimum(Weight w1, Weight w2, Weight w3) {
    // if the first weight is smaller than the second & third weight
    Weight minimum;    
    if(w1.lessThan(w2) && w1.lessThan(w3)){

      // return the first weight as the smallest weight
        minimum = w1;
        }
    // else if the second weight is smaller than the first & third weight
    else if (w2.lessThan(w1) && w2.lessThan(w3)){
      // return the second weight as the smallest weight
        minimum = w2;
        }
    // else the third weight is smaller than the first & second weight
    else{
        // return the third weight as the smallest weight
        minimum = w3;
        }
    System.out.println("\nThe minimum weight is " + minimum.toString());
    return minimum;
  }

  // a method that returns the highest weight among 3 weights

  private static Weight findMaximum(Weight w1, Weight w2, Weight w3) {
    // if the first weight is greater than the second & third weight
    Weight maximum;
    if (!w1.lessThan(w2) && !w1.lessThan(w3)){
      // return the first weight as the highest weight
      maximum = w1;
    }
    // else if the second weight is greater than the first & third weight
    else if (!w2.lessThan(w1) && !w2.lessThan(w3)){
      // return the second weight as the highest weight
      maximum = w2;
    }
    // else the third weight is greater than the first & second weight
    else{
      // return the third weight as the highest weight
      maximum = w3;
    }  
    System.out.println("\nThe maximum weight is " + maximum.toString());
    return maximum;
  }

  // a method that returns the average weight among 3 weights

    private static Weight findAverage(Weight w1, Weight w2, Weight w3) {
    // create a new Weight object
    Weight average = new Weight(0, 0);
    // add the weight of the three objects to the new Weight object
    // by invoking the addTo() method
    average.addTo(w1);
    average.addTo(w2);
    average.addTo(w3);
    average = average / 3;
    
 

    System.out.println("\nThe average weight is " + average.toString());
    return average;
  }

  
  
  // main method

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create three weight objects
    Weight weight1 = new Weight(25, 20);
    Weight weight2 = new Weight(30, 8);
    Weight weight3 = new Weight(23, 10);
    // display the 3 weights
    System.out.println("Weight 1: " + weight1.toString());
    System.out.println("Weight 2: " + weight2.toString());
    System.out.println("Weight 3: " + weight3.toString());
    // invoke the findMinimum() method to get the smallest weight among the 3
    // weights
    // display the minimum of the 3 weights
    Weight min = findMinimum(weight1, weight2, weight3);

    //findMinimum;
    // invoke the findMaximum() method to get the highest weight among the 3 weights
    Weight max = findMaximum(weight1, weight2, weight3);

    Weight avg = findAverage(weight1,weight2, weight3);


  }

}
```

The second file is where I need assistance.  In the findAverage method.

Comment: Weight is a class, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I won't give you the answer straight away as it really defeats the purpose of homework. However, I believe pointing you in the right direction will help. With that said, perhaps you can try to use arrays with for loops. For loops can be used to find the total amount and then you can get the amount of numbers through the size of the array. Then you can do total/size of array to get the average. I hope this helps!

Comment: So I have to use the "add.To" method from the Weight class.  would an array still work even though I have to use that method?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).